# Strategy to solve inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove $|x + y| = |x| + |y|$ iff $xy \ge 0$.

I don't understand a place to start. I was thinking of solving using contradiction but, as I am new to real analysis, I don't understand it.

Thanks

Comment: Square both sides and see if you can take it forward from there.

Comment: Go through the four cases (1) $x \lt 0, y \lt 0$. (2) $x \ge 0, y \lt 0$. (3) $x \ge 0, y \lt 0$. (4) $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

$$xy>0\iff x,y>0\;\;or\;\;x,y<0\implies \begin{cases}|x+y|=x+y=|x|+|y|&,\;\;x,y>0\\{}\\|x+y|=-x-y=|x|+|y|&,\;\;x,y<0\end{cases}$$

and OTOH

$$xy<0\implies x>0\,,\,\,y<0\,,\,\,\text{or the other way around, so assuming the first one:}$$

$$ \begin{cases}|x+y|=x+y>x-y=|x|+|y|&,\;\;x+y\ge0\\{}\\|x+y|=-x-y<x-y=|x|+|y|&,\;\;x+y<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: in the 1st line, the $x,y>0$ case, I think you meant it to be a $+$ sign instead of $=$.

Comment: True @Shubham. Thanksm good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Each occurrence of the absolute value function splits cases. For example if you consider $x \le 0$ and $x \ge 0$ separately then one absolute value function disappears. It's up to you to try splitting cases this way until the inequality is solved.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x + y| = |x| + |y|\iff(|x + y|)^2 = (|x| + |y|)^2\iff x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+y^2+2|x|\cdot|y|\iff xy=|x|\cdot|y|=|xy|\iff xy\geq 0$$
**Note.** $a^2=b^2$ does not imply $a=b$ in general, but here both sides are non-negative.