# proof of triangular inequality modified $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ iff $|xy|>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$$|x+y|=|x|+|y| \iff |xy|>0$$

I tried to prove the above inequality but i cant find a way. I tried assuming the first condition is true and tried to derive the second part of it but it seems i can't find a way to get through. I'm new to real analysis and it would be in great help if someone can provide me with a tip. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the second condition is $|xy|>0$ and not $xy>0$? Because it's pretty easy to find a counterexample to that, such as $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: I just noticed that this looks quite similar to your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811156/strategy-to-solve-inequalities (for which you accepted an answer).

Answer (score 1):

You want prove that
$$|x+y|=|x|+|y|\iff xy>0$$
which means that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign: to prove the necessary condition we do it by contrapositive so let $x$ and $y$ with opposite signs and prove that $|x+y|\ne|x|+|y|$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I hope so. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually $|x+y|=|x|+|y| \iff xy \ge 0$, i.e. if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign
or one of them is zero.

One way to see this is from

$$ |x + y|^2 = (x + y)^2  = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $$

and

$$ (|x| + |y|)^2 = |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2 = x^2 + 2|xy| + y^2$$

so that $|x+y|=|x|+|y| \iff xy = |xy| \iff xy \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks this helps :) thanks alot again